# How to autowire Service with-in JUnit Tests

Tags: java, spring, junit, autowired, spring-annotations

How to autowire Service in test class by only using  spring-annotations

when I try I got this error below , whereas  @Service annotation used in UserServiceImp class

> 2014-12-20 15:35:52 ERROR TestContextManager:334 - Caught exception
>   while allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@5af97850]
>   to prepare test instance [com.amsb.bariz.base.test.UserTest@4520ebad]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'com.amsb.bariz.base.test.UserTest': Injection
>   of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: public com.amsb.bariz.base.service.UserService
>   com.amsb.bariz.base.test.UserTest.userService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.amsb.bariz.base.service.UserService]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

my Service Class is

```
package com.amsb.bariz.base.service.imp;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.amsb.bariz.base.dao.UserDao;
import com.amsb.bariz.base.dao.UserRoleDao;
import com.amsb.bariz.base.entity.User;
import com.amsb.bariz.base.entity.UserRole;
import com.amsb.bariz.base.service.UserService;


@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImp implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private UserRoleDao userRoleDao;

    public void register(User user) {

        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        java.util.Date now = calendar.getTime();

        Date dateNow = new Date(20070266);
        Timestamp dn = new Timestamp(now.getTime());
        user.setStatus("P");
        user.setCreated_on(dn);
        user.setEnabled(false);

        UserRole ur = new UserRole(user,"USER_ROLE");


        System.out.println("XDXDX ::" + user.toString());
        userDao.create(user);
        userRoleDao.create(ur);

    }

}
```

my Test Class is :

```
package com.amsb.bariz.base.test;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener;

import com.amsb.bariz.base.dao.UserDao;
import com.amsb.bariz.base.entity.User;
import com.amsb.bariz.base.entity.UserRole;
import com.amsb.bariz.base.service.UserService;
import com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.amsb.bariz.base.service"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/spring-main.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
public class UserTest {


    @Autowired
    public UserService userService;



    @Test
    public void userAdd() {
        User user = new User();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        java.util.Date now = calendar.getTime();
        Timestamp doo = new Timestamp(now.getTime());



        Date a = new Date(0);


        user.setPassword("oman");
        user.setName("oman new ");
        user.setStatus("N");
        user.setCreated_on(doo);
        user.setUpdated_on(doo);
        user.setDob(new Date(20140522));
        user.setUsername("AHMED@A.com");


        userService.register(user);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you trying to use the test itself as a part of the Spring configuration? That's not going to work. What you need to do is: 
- remove the `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan` annotations from the test itself
- create a simple `TestConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.amsb.bariz.base.service"})
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/spring-main.xml")
public class TestConfiguration{ }
```

And just reference that in your test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfiguration.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class UserTest {
```

And you should be able to inject your service just fine.

Hope it helps.